# Django Rest Framework - Masking response values

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was wondering what the best way would be to mask a certain response parts. I will use an example to explain. Let's say I have a `Person` model with `first_name`, `last_name` and `email`. I use `PersonSerializer` to return that data.

An example response can be

```
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "email": "johndoe@gmail.com"
}
```

I want to "hide" an email when presenting it as response. I still want it to be present as the key, I just want to mask the value. So I want to achieve this response by first setting this class in my `PersonModel`

Class:

```
    class MASK:
        mask_fields = (
            'email'
            ...
        ) //there can be multiple values here
```

To get this response:

```
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "email": "__MSK__" // so it get's masked
}
```

So this should not impact the serialization when creating a new patient with same serializer class as well.

Anyone has idea what the best way would be? Maybe overriding `to_representation` method or?

Comment: Yep, probably overriding `to_representation`, maybe in a mixin class so you can add it wherever you need.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do you can just write your own mask function

```
class DemoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Demo
        fields = ("id","email")
    
    def get_email(self,obj):
        email_id = str(id) + "-" + random.randrange(1,9999999) 
        # you can write your on Hashing logic
        return email_id
```

For future references you can split from "-" and you got your obj ID

Comment: The problem with that is simply having to write method for every field I want to mask. It's not generic. I would love to mask every field based on the `mask_fields` in the model